# My Java Servlet (war) is not working on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8, easyapache-4

My java Servlet (war) http://localhost:8080/test/NewServlet works fine on localhost, but once I deploy on my website https://example.com/test/NewServlet it does not work. Page simply redirects to home page i.e. example.com
It was working fine earlier on prior version of EasyApache. After I updated to EA4 servlets are not working.
Servlet is compiled with jdk 1.8

Comment: Do you need a port address? E.g. https://example.com **:8080** /test/NewServlet?

Comment: my website is already hosted on Centos (vps). I think port address is required in case of localhost only.

Comment: you should access log file of that tomcat server and try to debug it

Comment: Cataline.out shows org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException